# Middle value using python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, median, python-3.4

UPDATED

```
a = int(input("Give a value: "))
b = int(input("Give a value: "))
c = int(input("Give a value: "))
def middle(a, b ,c) :
    m = min(a,b,c)
    M = max(a,b,c)
    return a+b+c-m-M
```

This is where im at. It takes my numbers into the data. How would I get it to display the middle one?! Sorry I'm so terrible at this. Way in over my head on this intro course. @CommuSoft @Zorg @paxdiablo and everyone else

Comment: too many spaces for your return statements?

Comment: Shouldn't you put a colon in the `def` line as well?

Comment: You must call the method. `def` means you *define* a method. The `a`, `b` and `c` are local variabeles in the `def` block. They don't have any relation with the earlier code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put a colon (`:`) on the first line (`def`) as well.

This works for the [online python environment](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_python3_online.php):

```
def input(a, b, c) :
    if a <= b <= c or c <= b <= a :
      return b
    elif b <= a <= c or c <= a <= b :
      return a
    else:
      return c
```

Furthermore it is more advisable to make use of min and max I guess. Min and max are sometimes directly supported by a CPU and there are implementations that avoid branching (if-then-else's):

```
def input(a, b, c) :
    m = min(a,b,c)
    M = max(a,b,c)
    return a+b+c-m-M
```

or:

```
def input(a, b, c) :
    return min(max(a,b),max(b,c),max(a,c))
```

The last one is also numerically stable.

In most cases if-then-else clauses should be avoided. They reduce the amount of pipelining although in interpreted languages this might not increase performance.

---

Based on the comments, I guess you want to write an interactive program. This can be done like:

```
def middle(a, b, c) : #defining a method
    return min(max(a,b),max(b,c),max(a,c))

a = int(input("Give a value: "))
b = int(input("Give b value: "))
c = int(input("Give c value: "))
print("The requested value is ")
print(middle(a,b,c)) #calling a method
```

*Defining* a method will never result in Python *using* that method. The `a`, `b` and `c` in the `def` block are not the `a`, `b` and `c` in the rest of your program. These are "other variables that happen to have the same name". In order to *call* a method. You write the methods name and between brackets the *parameters* with which you wish to call your method.

Comment: Thay's logical: you never asked Python to actually compute and print the middle of the three numbers. You should *call* your defined method

Comment: Your solution is confusing, purports to be fast (when we don't have any reason to care about speed) but is slow, doesn't work for non-numbers, etc. If we're looking for something alternative, `def middle(a, b, c): return sorted([a, b, c])[1]` is pretty nice (and robust).

Comment: @CommuSoft: This will not work, you need to change `input` to something else... Please use something like `middle`.

Comment: Your edit is of code that you never ran (which is clear since it doesn't work).

Comment: Now it does. Sometimes one wants to provide answers too fast :(

Comment: There we go! Now it works. Thanks so much! Im sorry I wasn't clear it should be interactive. One random last question. Is there anyway to keep they command box from closing right after it provides me with the answer? @CommuSoft

Comment: Well you could use `input()` (on the last line of your program), then it will wait until you hit enter.

Comment: @iMaxPrime: I've provided a third definition for such method that is more numerically stable. This can be important if the values are **not** integers, but floating points and have a large difference in value.

Answer (score 6):

Like others mentioned, you're missing a colon, but for simplicity sake:

```
def middle(a, b, c):
    return sorted([a, b, c])[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Post your full syntax error (or any other full traceback) whenever you're having trouble.

And your `def` line needs a colon.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
def middle(a,b,c):
    s={a,b,c}
    s-={min(s),max(s)}
    return s.pop()
```

What this does:

Create a set of the unduplicated values:

```
>>> a,b,c=1,2,3
>>> s={a,b,c}
>>> s
{1, 2, 3}
```

Remove the max and the min, leaving the middle:

```
>>> s-={min(s), max(s)}
>>> s
{2}
```

Pop the only remaining value:

```
>>> s.pop()
2
```

Comment: Seems like it would be a lot easier to just `return max(a,min(b,c))` ?

Comment: @user667648: That's wrong. Say that `a` is the absolute maximum, then `middle(3,2,1)` will return `3`.

Comment: @dawg: Ahh... Darn it... I feel like there should be a way to do it with min and max... I'll have to think about it more.

Comment: @user667648: simply `a+b+c-min(a,b,c)-max(a,b,c)`

Comment: @user667648: or by only using `min` and `max` operations: `min(max(a,b),max(b,c),max(a,c))`

Comment: @CommuSoft: Consider: `a,b,c=0,.1,1` for `a+b+c-min(a,b,c)-max(a,b,c)`

Comment: @dawg: For the provided numbers, this is not really an issue. People behind IEEE754 stated that for instance using equality on floating point numbers will have side effects. On the other hand it is indeed possible that by using a very small and very large number. The mantissa runs out of bits to store the values. The second provided way will however work.